Which version of Netscape, on which OS, appears in the movie “Cut” (2000)?
This is from the movie Cut (2000).
The browser is Netscape, but I have never seen this "skin".
Does anyone recognize the OS and version?


Looks like a reversed color monitor with an unmodified Netscape.

It looks like a late-stage (4.7x) release of Netscape Communicator running on Windows (probably Windows 98). Compare with a detail from this screenshot (listed in Visual design evolution of Netscape Navigator, copied from Lessons from 6 software rewrite stories):

The icons, chrome and fonts are the same as in your screenshot. The colours appear to be inverted; inverting your image (using the GIMP’s “value invert”) produces this:

which looks like a darker version of the snippet above (thanks to IMSoP).

Yes probably is a Windows 98 theme, i ever dislike themes in Windows version preferring original theme, so I forgot it about themes :)

Almost surely the colours are manipulated – Windows 9x themes can’t turn the address bar convex, or change icons.

Not to mention the godawful kerning on 'Vanessa', which is a Microsoft hallmark.

This is what the image from the question looks like if you run GIMP's "Value Invert": https://i.sstatic.net/38h3HYlD.png

From the dithering of the search icon I'm guessing that the computer's display wasn't set to true colour (24-bit or 32-bit).

@Neil Netscape used a 6x6x5(blue) color palette on 8-bit displays if the X server supported it having its own palette (can’t remember the term). Windows had a full 6x6x6 color cube.
